# UITextView stange animation glitch on paste action (iOS11)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, uitextview

I'm facing a very strange bug. When I paste anything inside `UITextView`, I receive a surprising glitch of animation.

To reproduce it I've just created a black `.xcodeproj`, added `UITextView` to `ViewController` via storyboard and ran the application.

The only similiar problem I've found is https://twitter.com/twostraws/status/972914692195790849
And it says that it's a bug of `UIKit` in iOS11. But there lot of applications on my iPhone with `UITextview` that works correctly on iOS11.
You can see the bug in the video here – https://twitter.com/twostraws/status/972914692195790849

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.
What I tried?
 - Tried the new clear project with minimal changes;
 - Disabled all the autocorrection types;
 - Removed constraints;
 - Tried on several iPhones with different version – 11.2.5 and 11.4.2.

The original project is attached. It's made on `Swift 4.1` with `Xcode 9.4(9F1027a)`
https://ufile.io/fzyj8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I checked some other applications on my iPhone like `Todoist` and found the same bug there. But also I've found the solution.
I hope Apple will urgently fix this bug.

So you may implement the `UITextPasteDelegate` and disabled the animation on paste action. This API is available only iOS11+, but it seems that the bug is also reproduced only on iOS11.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView.pasteDelegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextPasteDelegate {
    func textPasteConfigurationSupporting(_ textPasteConfigurationSupporting: UITextPasteConfigurationSupporting, shouldAnimatePasteOf attributedString: NSAttributedString, to textRange: UITextRange) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for finding this. This issue has been driving me crazy for a while. In my tests (before realising the existence of the UITextPasteDelegate option) the animation seemed more ok when working with a standard UITextView compared to more complicated use cases of UITextView (supporting resizing for keyboard appearance, responding to text events etc). I am still wondering of the underlying cause for the incorrect animation is a missing super call somewhere which leads to issues when iOS is taking a snapshot for the animation.

Comment: @solesignal I'm wondering too. I'll keep monitoring new iOS versions. Hope not to forget to write back here when the bug is fixed.

Comment: I see it too, in iOS 12. Wondering if it's an issue on my end or if it's still a bug in UIKit

Comment: This issue is resolved in iOS 13 but still existed in lower versions. Thanks for this amazing solution!