# UITextView's textContainer renders at the wrong frame when the height is changed

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

All I want is to resize the `UITextView` whenever you type/paste on it. It should be scrollable because I don't want the `UITextView` to fill up the screen. It could be easily achievable with these few lines of codes.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var mainTextViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.mainTextView.delegate = self
}

// This method is used for calculating the string's height in a UITextField
func heightOf(text: String, for textView: UITextView) -> CGFloat {
    let nsstring: NSString = text as NSString
    let boundingSize = nsstring.boundingRect(
        with: CGSize(width: textView.frame.size.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude),
        options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [.font: textView.font!],
        context: nil).size
    return ceil(boundingSize.height + textView.textContainerInset.top + textView.textContainerInset.bottom)
}

// This method calculates the UITextView's new height
func calculateHeightFor(text: String, in textView: UITextView) -> CGFloat {
    let newString: String = textView.text ?? ""
    let minHeight = self.heightOf(text: "", for: textView) // 1 line height
    let maxHeight = self.heightOf(text: "\n\n\n\n\n", for: textView) // 6 lines height
    let contentHeight = self.heightOf(text: newString, for: textView) // height of the new string
    return min(max(minHeight, contentHeight), maxHeight)
}

// The lines inside will change the UITextView's height
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.mainTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = calculateHeightFor(
        text: textView.text ?? "", 
        in: textView)
}
```

This works perfectly well, except when the you paste a multi-line text, or when you press **enter** (line break).

---

To solve the pasting issue, various SO questions suggested that I either create a subclass of `UITextView` to override the `paste(_:)` method or I use the `textView(_: shouldChangeTextIn....)` delegate method. After a few experiments with both the best answer was to use the `shouldChangeTextIn` method which resulted my code into this

```
// I replaced `textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)` with this
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    self.mainTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = calculateHeightFor(
        text: ((textView.text ?? "") as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text), 
        in: textView)
    return true
}
```

---

Now what should happen is that when the you paste text the `UITextView` should look like this. (The pasted string is "A\nA\nA\nA\nA" or 5 lines of just A's)

[image]

However it becomes like this

[image]

As you can see from the screenshots, the textContainer's frame is at the wrong position. Now the weird thing about this is that it seems to only happen when you're pasting at an empty `UITextView`.

I've tried setting and resetting the `UITextView`'s frame.size, I've tried manually setting the `NSTextContainer`'s size, and some other hacky solutions but I just can't seem to fix it. How can I solve this?

Additional Information:

Upon looking at the view debugger, here's how it looks like when you type **enter** (line break)

[image]
[image]

As we can see, the text container is at the wrong location.

---

After all this adding a `UIView.animate` block seems to fix some of the issues but not all of it. Why does this work?

```
// These snippet kind of fixes the problem
self.mainTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = calculateHeightFor(
    text: textView.text ?? "", 
    in: textView)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Note: I didn't place the `UIView.animate` solution because it doesn't cover all the bugs.

**Note:**

OS Support: iOS 8.xx - iOS 12.xx
Xcode: v10.10
Swift: 3 and 4 (I tried on both)

**PS:** yes I have already been on other SO questions such ones listed on the bottom and a few others

- [TextContainer isn't resizing while changing bounds of UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913105/textcontainer-isnt-resizing-while-changing-bounds-of-uitextview)
- [UITextView's text going beyond bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889657/uitextviews-text-going-beyond-bounds)
- [UITextView stange animation glitch on paste action (iOS11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770900/uitextview-stange-animation-glitch-on-paste-action-ios11)
- [How to calculate TextView height base on text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268477/how-to-calculate-textview-height-base-on-text)

Answer (score -1):

You can ignore all the code for calculating height and use the set the textview attribute scrolling Enabled = false
the textview will adjust it self to fit with the text content
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUGtg.png)

then change the code as you want

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textView.text = "A\nA\nA\nA\nA"
}
```

The result will be like this 
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvG8c.png)

Comment: Nope, that doesn't solve my problem, let me edit my question so it can be clearer.